# Connect two meshes: bridging edges

Tags: modeling

So im pretty new to the modeling scene ofc trying to teach myself but I came to this problem (see pic). I made the hand separate and having problems connecting it to my base model,and ive tried merging and bridging edges but nothing happens? TY in advance.[image]

Comment: Connect as in specific vertices connecting or just merge into one object?  If a merge, select both and menu to Object -> Join (ctrl-J)

Comment: Could you give a little more detail about what you tried and what's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Outliner* I see you have two objects selected and you're in *Edit Mode* with both of them.

[image: two objects in edit mode]

You can't run the operations you've tried on vertices from separate objects.

As james_t suggests, you first need to tab back to *Object Mode*, select both of the objects and *Join* them into one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.  Then you can enter *Edit Mode* and perform the operation.

Comment: Thank you both! Thats exactly what I needed to do! Glad Ik that now too